# How to manage if response as string in fetch api in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have using default fetch api react-native.
May api response as string so how can I manage.

Example of code

```
fetch(baseURL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: reqHeader,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('=== ==== ===');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.json[][1]()));
      })
      .then(result => {
      })
      .catch(error => {
      });
  });
```

I am not able to get "Email already exists." string showing in attached image..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utBLi.png)
Thanks

Comment: Can you `console.log` the response only so we can see what's being returned?

Comment: Nothing return. Going to error block because .json not parse.